# How do you fix error when launching Ganache after installation

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ganache

This error always pops up when I launch Ganache after installing it how do I fix it?

Ganache encountered an error. Help us fix it by raising a GitHub issue!

Mention the following error information when writing your ticket, and please include as much information as possible. Sorry about that!

Error: connection not open

````
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Ganache_2.1.2.0_x64__zh355ej5cj694\app\resources\app.asar\node_modules\web3-providers-ws\src\index.js:267:19)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)
    at listOnTimeoutNT (timers.js:340:26)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)```
````

Comment: windows? linux? ganache version?

Comment: try with the lastest beta version:https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases/tag/v2.0.1-beta.0